# Cannot input a 2D array in c++ using for

Tags: c++

I'm trying to input a 2D array in c++ but my code doesn't even get to calculation lines:

```
int dim1, dim2;
cout << "Enter first dimension: ";
cin >> dim1;
cout << endl << "Enter second dimension: ";
cin >> dim2;
int arr[dim1][dim2];
for (int i = 1; i <= dim1; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= dim2; j++) {
        cin >> arr[i][j];
    }
}
for (int i = 1; i <= dim1; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= dim2; j++) {
        cout << arr[i][j] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Note that `int arr[dim1][dim2];` when `dim1` and `dim2` are not constant expressions is not really valid C++. It's only available as an extension is some compilers. It's called a _Variable Length Array_ or  _VLA_ for short. Use `std::vector`s instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, you should start inputing an array in c++ from 0, so your loop should begin with `i = 0` and should be stopped when `i == n`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dim1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dim2; j++) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has two problems.

First, [VLA arrays is not valid C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). You have to use `std::vector`.

Second. C++ array indexes start at `0` and end at `size - 1`. But you are looping from `1` to `n`. This creates out-of-bounds.

Your code should look like this:

```
int dim1, dim2;
std::cout << "Enter first dimension: ";
std::cin >> dim1;
std::cout << endl << "Enter second dimension: ";
std::cin >> dim2;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr;
arr.resize(dim1, std::vector<int>(dim2));
for (int i = 0; i < dim1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dim2; j++) {
        std::cin >> arr[i][j];
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < dim1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dim2; j++) {
        std::cout << arr[i][j] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Instead of creating the vector and then `resize` it, you could create it with the proper dimensions directly: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr(dim1, std::vector<int>(dim2));` Anyway, +1

Answer (score 1):

**First** in C++, the size of an array must be a **compile-time constant**.So,  take for example the following code snippets:

```
int n = 10;
int arr[n]; //INCORRECT because n is not a constant expression
```

The correct way to write the above would be:

```
const int n = 10;
int arr[n]; //CORRECT
```

Similarly, the following(which you did in your code example) is incorrect:

```
    int dim1, dim2;
    cout << "Enter first dimension: "; 
    cin >> dim1;
    cout << endl << "Enter second dimension: ";
    cin >> dim2;
    int arr[dim1][dim2];//INCORRECT
```

You should instead use `std::vector<>` as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 

int main()
{
    int dim1, dim2;
    std::cout << "Enter first dimension: ";
    std::cin >> dim1;
    std::cout << std::endl << "Enter second dimension: ";
    std::cin >> dim2;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr(dim1, std::vector<int>(dim2));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < dim1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dim2; j++) {
            std::cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dim1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dim2; j++) {
            std::cout << arr[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```